# java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: call 1 of 2: Router(mockRouter#172).xyz()) was not called

Tags: kotlin, mockk, mockk-verify

I am getting weird issue when running on my unit test.  I have this function

```
internal fun getPendingStatusAction(
status: XYZ
): (() -> Unit)? {
    var action: (() -> Unit)? = null
    this.yo = yo
    if (isAwaitingIdVerification(status)) {
        action = {
            router.xyz()
        }
    } else if (status == XYZ.PURCHASE) {
        action = {
            router.xyz()
        }
    }
    return action
}
```

When I run single unit test it complete fine, but when I run whole file unit test it failed.

```
@Test
fun `getPendingStatusAction - `() {
    // STUBBING
    val mockStatus = XYZ.VERIFICATION
    every { subject.isAwaitingIdVerification(any()) } returns true
    // EXECUTION
    val action = subject.getPendingStatusAction(mockStatus)
    action?.invoke()

    // VERIFICATION
    verify {
        router.xyz()
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

```
Verification failed: call 1 of 2: Router(mockRouter#172).xyz()) was not called
java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: call 1 of 2: Router(mockRouter#172).xyz()) was not called
```

Comment: What's the `)` on a line on its own, in the verify block? Is it a typo?

Comment: Also, there is something strange about "Router(mockRouter#172).xyz)" - shouldn't that be "Router(mockRouter#172).xyz()"?

Comment: yes it type and it should be xyz().

Comment: Is router a mock that you pass to the system under test?

Comment: yes `@MockK private lateinit var mockRouter: Router`